# How to random question in Android with Array

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

Please help me to complete my project. I'm try to show the question with no random. 
I have to file in here first the question in file **Soalpilihan.java** and the execution to answer and show the question in file **QuizGameActivity.java**.
And this how to random the question if i save the question array in other file and put the question to the file other and random it.

This is the code **QuizGameActivity.java**

```
package com.belajarbahasajerman;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizGameActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnback;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Uri uri;
    TextView tvSoal;
    Button OptionA, OptionB, OptionC;
    int skor=0;
    int arr;
    int x; 
    Boolean clicked1=false,clicked2=false,clicked3=false;
    String jawaban;

    Soalpilihan soalPG = new Soalpilihan();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.quizgame);

        btnback=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnback3);
        uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.btn_klik);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
        tvSoal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Soal);
        OptionA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionA);
        OptionB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionB);
        OptionC = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OptionC);

        setKonten();
        OptionA.setOnClickListener(this);
        OptionB.setOnClickListener(this);
        OptionC.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.OptionA:
                mp.start();
                if(OptionA.getText().toString().equals(jawaban)){
                    skor = skor + 10;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Jawaban Benar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setKonten();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Jawaban Salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setKonten();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.OptionB:
                mp.start();
                if(OptionB.getText().toString().equals(jawaban)){
                    skor = skor + 10;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Jawaban Benar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setKonten();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Jawaban Salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setKonten();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.OptionC:
                mp.start();
                if(OptionC.getText().toString().equals(jawaban)){
                    skor = skor + 10;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Jawaban Benar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setKonten();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Jawaban Salah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setKonten();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setKonten(){
        arr = soalPG.pertanyaan.length;
        if(x >= arr){
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizGameActivity.this, HasilSkoring.class);
            i.putExtra("skorAkhir",skor);
            i.putExtra("activity","PilihanGanda");
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            tvSoal.setText(soalPG.getPertanyaan(x));
            OptionA.setText(soalPG.getPilihanJawaban1(x));
            OptionB.setText(soalPG.getPilihanJawaban2(x));
            OptionC.setText(soalPG.getPilihanJawaban3(x));
            jawaban = soalPG.getJawabanBenar(x);

        }
        x++;
    }

}
```

This is the code **Soalpilihan.java**

```
package com.belajarbahasajerman;

public class Soalpilihan {
    public String pertanyaan[] = 
        {" Bahasa Jerman 'Nama saya' adalah ",
         " Ada berapa huruf yang ada di bahasa Jerman ? ",
         " Angka tiga dalam bahasa Jerman yaitu ",
         " Ich bin ... Jahre alt adalah menyatakan tentang ",
         " Di bahasa Jerman mengucapkan selamat malam adalah ",
         " Ketika berpisah dengan seseorang, kamu harus mengatakan(dalam formal) ? ",
         " elf + vier adalah ",
         " Terima kasih dalam bahasa Jerman ",
         " Sechs, sieben, acht, ... lanjutannya adalah ",
         " Guten tag adalah ucapan pada saat ? ",
    };

    private String pilihjaw[][] = {
            {"Ich heiße","Ich komme","Ich reise mit"},
            {"26 huruf","28 huruf","30 huruf"},
            {"drei","thri","zwei"},
            {"Saya berasal","Nama saya","Umur saya"},
            {"Guten Tag","Gute Nacht","Guten Morgen"},
            {"Tschuss","Auf Wiedersehen","Gute bay"},
            {"15","14","16"},
            {"Bitte","Danke","Sankyu"},
            {"Zehn","Funf","Neun"},
            {"Selamat siang","Selamat malam","Selamat pagi"},
    };

    private String jawbenar[] = {
            "Ich heiße",
            "30 huruf",
            "drei",
            "Umur saya",
            "Gute Nacht",
            "Auf Wiedersehen",
            "15",
            "Danke",
            "Neun",
            "Selamat siang",
    };

    public String getPertanyaan(int x){
        String soal = pertanyaan[x];
        return soal;
    }

    public String getPilihanJawaban1(int x){
        String jawaban1 = pilihjaw[x][0];
        return jawaban1;
    }

    public String getPilihanJawaban2(int x){
        String jawaban2 = pilihjaw[x][1];
        return jawaban2;
    }

    public String getPilihanJawaban3(int x){
        String jawaban3 = pilihjaw[x][2];
        return jawaban3;
    }

    public String getJawabanBenar(int x){
        String jawaban = jawbenar[x];
        return jawaban;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have methods that get a String based on a number passed in.

For example:

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
String randomPertanyaan = getPertanyaan(random);
```

Boolean Helper

You will have to play around with the logic.

```
public boolean correctAnswer(int random, int answer){
    String randomPertanyaan = getPertanyaan(random);
    String getAnswers = getAnswers(random, answer);
    if (answer == //userinput) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

getAnswers

```
public String getAnswers(int random, int answer){
    String getAnswer = pilihjaw[random][answer]; //random is the ROW for the question, answer is that ANSWER.
    return getAnswer;
}
```

Comment: Ok the question done random but... what about the answer ? How to match the question and answer ?

Comment: you need to store that somewhere. for example, if i have a question in index 4, then I know that my question and the set of answers are within the same index, right? So, Question, The sky is what color? Set of answers ("blue", "red", "orange"). I have to tell my program the answer is 1 (or 0). You can create a boolean method that takes in the random int for the question, and also a random int for the answer.

Comment: see my updated answer @AlvinIndra you will have to play around with the logic.